# CSS loading time

Tags: css

I created a personal website with the template from HTML5UP.net: https://html5up.net/identity

In the main.css file there is a body style with a background image. I replaced the image with the url from unsplash.com. This way every time the page loads, there is a new random background image.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
    background-repeat: repeat,          no-repeat,          no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px, cover,                cover;
    background-position: top left,      center center,      bottom center;
    background-attachment: fixed,           fixed,              fixed;
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that my website is loading slowly. When the background is fully loaded, the rest of my website appears.

Is there a way that i can load this part of the CSS stylesheet at the end?

Comment: You can do it with javascript

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Yeah, Im taking care of it ^^

Comment: The template's JavaScript is set to render the rest of the page only when all assets have loaded completely. There's nothing you can do in CSS to prevent this; you'll have to edit the template's JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function loadStyleSheet()
{
        var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
        stylesheet.href = 'assets/css/bg.css';
        stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
        stylesheet.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
}
</script>
```

bg.css:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080");
    background-repeat: repeat,          no-repeat,          no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px, cover,                cover;
    background-position: top left,      center center,      bottom center;
    background-attachment: fixed,           fixed,              fixed;
}
```

main.css:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("../../images/bg.jpg");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("../../images/bg.jpg");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("../../images/bg.jpg");
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255, 165, 150, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 228, 255, 0.35)), url("../../images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat,          no-repeat,          no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px, cover,                cover;
    background-position: top left,      center center,      bottom center;
    background-attachment: fixed,           fixed,              fixed;
}
```

Now the page loads before the background.